# Setfacl permissions ignored for file copied over sftp

Tags: permissions, sftp, acl

I have set the permissions for the /var/www/html directory in my Raspberry Pi like this:

```
# file: .
# owner: www-data
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

The other day I needed to copy a file from my PC running Ubuntu to this directory, so I used SFTP.The permissions for the original file are:

```
# file: zerotier_1.1.14-2_brcm63xx.ipk
# owner: lucas
# group: lucas
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

But when the file was copied over I realized that it hadn't been created with the defined ACL permissions:

```
# file: zerotier_1.1.14-2_brcm63xx.ipk
# owner: pi
# group: pi
user::rw-
group::rwx                      #effective:r--
group:www-data:rwx              #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::---
```

But if I create a file manually with the same user, it works as expected:

```
pi@Gawain /var/www/html $ echo "test" > testfile
pi@Gawain /var/www/html $ getfacl testfile
# file: testfile
# owner: pi
# group: pi
user::rw-
group::rw-
group:www-data:rwx              #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: SFTP in openssh does not support extended ACLs.

Comment: Rsync -a keeps ACLs

Comment: I tried rsync and got this: `# file: zerotier_1.1.14-2_brcm63xx.ipk
# owner: pi
# group: pi
user::rw-
group::rw-                      #effective:r--
group:www-data:rwx              #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--`

Comment: As Jakuje stated, this is a problem with SFTP. He also created a full answer, with a workaround, to a similar question at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237967/155235